# getting Invalid parameter when try to send the JSON request,to create a folder in BOX-API

Tags: json, box

```
 {
      "name":"New Folder", 
      "parent": 
      {
        "id": "0"
      }
 }
{
  "type": "error"
   "status": 400
   "code": "bad_request"
   "context_info": {
   "errors": [1]
    0:  {
   "reason": "invalid_parameter"
    "name": "entity-body"
    "message": "Invalid valu
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be seeing this error if there is an existing folder in your Box account with the name "New Folder".

I would suggest trying this API call again with a different name for the new folder.